# Jquery fadeOut queue

Tags: jquery

I have two div's.  One with a black background and one purple.  I use jquery to fade out the black div and also to fade in the purple one.  However it seems as if both are trying to happen at the same time.

My question is how do I make the the purple div fade in after and only after the purple div has completely faded out.  I have heard of the queue method but I am not clear on how to use it.

```
$("div.black").fadeOut();
$("div.purple").fadeIn().queue(); // <-- purple div still trys to fade in
// while black div is fading out.  
// I need the purple div to wait 
// until that black div has completely faded out.
```

Comment: add callback to black div `fadeOut` and from callback `fadeIn` purple div. So that `fadeIn` will occur once black goes away.

Comment: unrelated to the answer, but you really shouldn't qualify your selectors with tagnames unless absolutely necessary. it doesn't serve any benefit, and creates a slower selector.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like this

```
$("div.black").fadeOut(function(){
    $("div.purple").fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: damn you quick answerer! :D

Comment: beat me to it! well-played, sir.

Answer (score 3):

try this using the callback

```
$("div.black").fadeOut(400,function(){
    $("div.purple").fadeIn().queue();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

fadeIn / fadeOut take a callback function as one of their parameters. That function is executed as soon as the animation is complete:

```
$(".black").fadeOut(function() {
    // this will run once the fadeOut animation is complete
    $(".purple").fadeIn();
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/fAbBn/

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using setTimeout, which takes a function and a time to wait in milliseconds. I think something like this should work:

```
$("div.black").fadeOut(500);
setTimeout(function() {
    $("div.purple").fadeIn()
}, 600)
```